# Fgets about the third parameter

Tags: c, file

I have this fragment

```
fseek(sp,f_line*fm,SEEK_SET);
fgets(buffer,LEN,(FILE*)sp);
```

I don't understand this part

> ```
>  (FILE)sp
> ```

I try to fill a char array with data from a file.

Comment: Please show the declaration of `sp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, someone thinks they are storing a file pointer in a variable `sp` that is not of type `FILE *`, so it is reputed to be necessary to cast the type to `FILE *`.  See the POSIX definition of [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html), which is meant to be equivalent to the [standard C](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.7.2) definition of the function.

However, given that the prior line calls `fseek()` with an uncast `sp`, and `fseek()` also expects a `FILE *`, someone is confused — the person writing the cast is confused.

- The cast should be removed from the call to `fgets()`.

Or, possibly but implausibly, the cast should be added to the call to `fseek()`.

---

One outré possibility is that the user defined `void *sp` and used that to store the `FILE *` returned by `fopen()` or equivalent.  Such a decision would be extremely unorthodox, and pointlessly opens up the code to type confusion, but could actually allow the code shown below to compile and run — but the cast is still unnecessary.

```
/* Abominable code - do not use! */
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    void *sp = fopen("abuse47.c", "r");    // The abomination!
    if (sp != 0)
    {
        char buffer[256];
        fseek(sp, 120, SEEK_SET);
        if (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), sp) != 0)
            printf("[%s]\n", buffer);
        fclose(sp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```